# Compact Embedding of Sobolev Valued Functions

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, compactness, sobolev-spaces

I am wondering if it is possible to show $L^{2}((0,T),H^{1}(\Omega))$ is compactly embedded in $L^{2}((0,T),L^{2}(\Omega))$. It's certainly true that $H^{1}(\Omega)$ is compactly embedded in $L^{2}(\Omega)$ however I am unsure if the prior is true.

I have that $\Omega$ is smooth with bounded boundary. So given a bounded subset $\mathcal{F}$ of $L^{2}((0,T),H^{1}(\Omega))$ I can extend trivially in time by zero outside $(0,T)$ and I have the existence of a extension operator $P$ so that $P(\mathcal{F})$ is a bounded subset of $L^{2}(\mathbb{R},H^{1}(\mathbb{R}))\subset L^{2}(\mathbb{R},L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{N}))$. The aim is to try and show that $\lim_{|h|\to 0}\|\tau_{h}f-f\|_{2}=0$ uniformly in $f\in\mathcal{F}$ (where $\tau_{h}f:=f(x+h)$) which implies compactness of $\mathcal{F}|_{(0,T)\times\Omega}$ in $L^{2}((0,T)\times\Omega)=L^{2}((0,T),L^{2}(\Omega))$ (Theorem 4.26 Brezis).

I believe I have the desired convergence if I translate in space but I am unsure if this will work if I translate in time. Is this a result anyone has come across before? If so, where might I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $$\Omega = [0,1]. $$
Define
$$
f_n(t,x) = 1_{(2^{-(n+1)},2^{-n})}(t) \cdot 2^{\frac{n+1}{2}},
$$
where $n$ is large enough so the interval is contaiend in $[0,T]$.
Then
$$
\|f_n\|_{L^2((0,T), H^1([0,1]))}^2 = \int_0^T \int_0^1 f_n(t,x)^2 + \partial_x f_n(t,x)^2 \,dx \,dt 
$$
$$
= \int_{2^{-(n+1)}}^{2^{-n}} \int_0^1 (2^\frac{n+1}{2})^2 + 0 \,dx \,dt
= 2^{-(n+1)} 2^{n+1} = 1.
$$
Hence $f_n$ is a bounded sequence in $L^2((0,T), H^1([0,1]))$.
But you can directly see that for $k \neq n$ you get
$$
\|f_n - f_k\|_{L^2((0,T), L^2([0,1]))}^2
= \|f_n\|_{L^2((0,T), L^2([0,1]))}^2 + \|f_k\|_{L^2((0,T), L^2([0,1]))}^2 = 1 + 1 = 2,
$$
because the subsets of $[0,T] \times [0,1]$ where the functions are non-zero are disjoint.
Hence the sequence can not have a convergent subsequence in $L^2((0,T), L^2([0,1]))$.

Comment: In your last equality you split the norm since the functions have disjoint support but why does a difference become a sum?

Comment: inside the integral you have $|f_k - f_j|^2 = |f_k|^2 + |-f_j|^2$. You can see this by checking first the set where f_k is nonzero and hence f_j is zero, and then the set where f_j is nonzero and hence f_k is zero.